# How to rewrite url using .htaccess and make url SEO friendly?

Tags: .htaccess

I have one website and i getting ulr in browser like this : www.abc.com/?i=1
I registered domain on http://www.freenom.com and they provide url like this.

So, SEO analysis tool said your website url not SEO friendly.

So, How to make website url SEO friendly using .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your current url format to `http://example.com/1` to make it search engine friendly.

To convert `/?i=1` to `/1` you can use the following RewriteRule in your `/.htaccess` .

```
RewriteEngine on

# externally redirect from /?i=foobar to /footboar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?i=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1? [L,R]
# internally map /footboar to /?i=foobar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?i=$1 [L]
```